# Display single column mysql data in multiple columns in php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I want to display MySQL data in HTML page, which looks something like the table below.

```
I want something like this:                
 +-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
 | Train Type  |TraNo  | Dep. Station| Dep. Time  | Arr. Station | Arr. Time |
 +-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
 | Fast        | 81    |Taipei       | 7:48       | Taitung      | 13:04     |
 +-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+

But I have this:
 +-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
 | Train Type  |TraNo  | Dep. Station| Dep. Time  | Arr. Station | Arr. Time |
 +-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
 | Fast        | 81    |Taitung      | 13:04      | Taitung      | 13:04     |
 +-------------+-------+-------------+------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I have confirmed that the SQL query is correct. [here's the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSXX6.png)

```
$sql = "SELECT ttype.TyName, train.TraNo, a.StaName, c.Time,b.StaName , d.Time
                FROM (((((ttype RIGHT JOIN train
                ON ttype.TyNo=train.TyNo)
                RIGHT JOIN pass c
                ON train.TraNo=c.TraNo)
                RIGHT JOIN station a
                ON a.StaNo=c.StaNo)
                RIGHT JOIN pass d
                ON train.TraNo=d.TraNo)
                RIGHT JOIN station b
                ON b.StaNo=d.StaNo)      

                WHERE c.Time < d.Time
                AND a.StaName='Taipei' 
                AND b.StaName='Taitung' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die("can't reach" . mysqli_error( ));

        $data = array(); // create a variable to hold the information

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          $data[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array
          ?>
          <?php print_r($data); ?>
            <!--<tr>
                <td><?php echo $data ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $row['TyName']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['TraNo']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['StaName']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Time']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['StaName']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Time']?></td>
            </tr>
            -->

        <?php
            }
        ?>
```

I have tried the PHP array but the printed info shows that PHP overlaps the departure station with arrival station data.  [array shows overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZveaJ.png)
Also, I tried the HTML table method, but the result is overlapping too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give alias at the sql stmt.

> `SELECT ttype.TyName, train.TraNo, a.StaName as dstation, c.Time as dtime,b.StaName as astation , d.Time as atime`

When retrieve, retrieve using

```
 <?php echo $row['dstation']?>
 <?php echo $row['dTime']?>
 <?php echo $row['astation']?>
 <?php echo $row['aTime']?>
```